# Laravel creating wrong table

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I need to have the download history of every user that's going to use our system (basically, a system for users to download posts for social media). I've created a "DownloadHistory" model, that has **ID**, **Timestamp**, **download_history** and **user_id** fields. When i create my user, an instance of DownloadHistory is supposed to be created automatically, and the users table is updated  to have the field **download_history_id** to have the newly created **DownloadHistory's** id, as seen in my RegisterController:

```
$downloadHistory = DownloadHistory::create([
    'user_id' => $user->id
]);

DB::table('users')->where('id', $user->id)->update(['download_history_id' => $downloadHistory->id]);
```

The problem is: I'm getting an error, that makes no sense in my mind:[image]

The reason why it doens't make sense to me is, i never created **download_histories**, but i did create **download_history**, so what is this ???
My DownloadHistory model is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DownloadHistory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
       'downloads' => 'array',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

And my migration for creating the table is:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateDownloadHistoryTable extends Migration
{  
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('download_history', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();                        
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->json('history');
            $table->integer('user_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('download_history');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table names are assumed plural in Laravel.

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#table-names

To fix, use `$table` property in your Model.

```
protected $table = 'download_history';
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `protected $table = 'download_history';` in your model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DownloadHistory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'download_history';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
       'downloads' => 'array',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: that worked! the table should've been in plural..

Answer (score 0):

Table names are assumed plural in Laravel.
To fix add protected $table = 'download_history'; in your model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DownloadHistory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'download_history';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
       'downloads' => 'array',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix Add protected $table = 'download_history'; in model

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).